# how to use a rootfs to create a bootable initrd and how to use it with qemu-system-arm

Tags: qemu

How to convert a rootfs into a bootable initrd file for use with qemu-system-arm in termux and how to use it

Comment: Have you tried researching on https://github.com/termux/